# How to get select item from md-select angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

This is my code to fill select list.

```
    <md-option ng-value="brand.name" ng-repeat="brand in brands">{{ brand.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

I want the brand user select should be available in scope variable selectedBrand

But it giving me undefined.

What is wrong with above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div layout="row">
    <md-select class="inline-flex md-select-down" placeholder="Select" ng-model="selectedBrand">
      <md-option ng-repeat="item in brands" value="{{item.name}}">
        {{item.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
 </div>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/lFgzw1I94o7pXg6tRNTX?p=preview)**